# Installing unpublished gem results in "no such file to load"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, irb

I'm building a local gem, and I'm wanting to be able to test and use it in pry. I'm creating my gem via `bundle gem blah`.

- `gem list` shows the gem.
- `gem contents blah` confirms it's installed in a location that's in my GEMPATH.
- `gem "blah", :path => "path/to/gem"` makes it available in the rails console.

But when I simply try and require it, its internal `require "file"` code seems not to be working. I started an example gem with the following structure:

```
├── Gemfile
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── Rakefile
├── blah.gemspec
├── lib
│   ├── blah
│   │   ├── ugh.rb
│   │   └── version.rb
│   └── blah.rb
└── pkg
    └── blah-0.0.1.gem
```

Where /lib/blah.rb begins with:

```
require "blah/version"
require "blah/ugh"
```

And when I try to load it in pry, IRB, or via `ruby -rubygems -e 'require "blah"'`, I get:

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- blah/ugh (LoadError)
```

Any ideas what could be causing this discrepancy? I feel like I'm doing things in order with practices established by Bundler and other gems, but perhaps I'm going awry somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to specify the load path when running ruby directly. This ensures that your all the files that you require relatively in your gem are found as well.

So when calling ruby in the rails root dir it should be

`ruby -rubygems -Ilib -e 'require "blah"'`

or in the pry case

`pry -I lib ...`

Hope that helps.